# Should broken fog light lens fail the state inspection?

Tags: lights, inspection, fog

My Subaru Forester has factory-installed fog lights (w/ Driver Assist) below the bumper. This item is an upgrade of the Limited trim level. Premium and lower trim levels have no fog lights.

Some time ago one of the lights got hit by something and the lens was smashed. Shortly after, the light stopped working. The other side works well.

I need to get the MA state inspection for the car. Fixing the light is some $350 at the dealer. Replacement parts on ebay are about $100.

The question is - since this is not a standard accessory, could a broken light fail the state inspection, or is it safe to do the inspection regardless?

Comment: You may run into one of those little clauses that say if it's on the vehicle, it has to be working. To save a buck, consider to remove it. If it's not state regulated equipment and it's not there, it can't fail the inspection.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the actual state regulations.  But my guess is that this will fail inspection since a damaged fog light could present safety problems for other drivers.  But if you simply remove it there should not be any problems.

Comment: A $100 replacement for something you can do yourself seems like the solution to me.

Comment: @GdD - yes, I found a video on how to install kit lights, so that enabled me to get to the assembly. The problem is that there is one screw that is held by a rusty U-style spring nut, which seems impossible to unscrew w/o damaging the soft mounting plastic. Subaru designers must had the dealer cash flow in mind when they chose such fasteners.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - the thought crossed in my mind, given the low price of aftermarket bezels (covers). I am not sure how inspector takes the fact that the switch is on the lights lever, but no lights are present. Also, this will impact resale price.

Comment: @jwh20 - the dealer said it'll fail an inspection in the last maintenance visit I had. It does not make too much sense to me, so I asked here.

Comment: Remember that you're talking about state regulations.  Making sense, especially in a place like MA, should not be expected.

Comment: @jwh20 - damn true!

Comment: Nobody is saying it's going to fail an inspection because of it @ysap, every state's regulations are different and there's test center interpretations as well.

Comment: @ysap, it sounds like a job for wd40 to me. A few sprays over a few hours left to soak in may just sort it out.

Comment: Tried calling your state's DMV for clarification? Tried calling your local inspection station or visiting one in person with or without the car? Visited your DMV online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After visiting the inspection station for a second time, I was able to talk to the tester himself. He explained that they work according to a checklist that is generated automatically, and includes all the things they must check. It goes according to the specific model and trim. Thus, he will have to fail the inspection for that car.